# ODBC Connection with odbcad32.exe

Tags: java, sql, odbc

I'm using Windows 7 64 bit version and I have installed Office 32 bit Version.
Currently I am developing a library management system by  using Access.

The problem I am having is that whenever I try to connect to the Access file I am getting 
following error.

Errorjava.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application

I tried  by running following ODBC version also from windows

c:\windows\sysWOW64\odbcad32.exe

I did connect my access file  from that. But still I am getting above error.

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense that you'd need a 64 bit driver for a 64 bit OS?  Why are you using Access instead of SQL Server, MySQL, PostgreSQL, or any other relational database?

Comment: Which version of Java are you running (32/64-bit)?

Comment: @duffymo  thanks for you  reply. Yeas I'm using MySQL (navicat) for my other java applications. but for this project we have been specially asked by our lecture  to created db in Access. Yeas as you and ederollora suggested ill reinstall office 64 and try run the application.

Comment: @Cory How can we check the java version ?

Comment: You're still out of luck - there's no JDBC-ODBC bridge driver in 64 bit JVMs from Oracle.  Sun added it in 32-bit JDK 1.0, but it's not available now.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem a couple of days ago. First you should try to use the 32-bit JDK (For example: JDK version 6u45 would be = `"Windows x86 ---  69.85 MB --- jdk-6u45-windows-i586.exe"` ) and check if using 32-bit JDK and 32-bit driver works together works.

In case it doesn't work, you should uninstall the 32-bit Office version and install a 64bit version which will carry the suitable 64-bit driver you need. Once you install it, you'll be able to run the java app and connect to the database properly.

You can also try to download [this file](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255) (AccessDatabaseEngine_X64.exe) that will install the driver on your computer (In my case I needed to query an Access database, don't know if that's your case) but I think it won't let you install it until you uninstall the 32-bit driver.

Note:

As [Cory](https://stackoverflow.com/users/74757/cory) states: "if you ever want to build an SSIS package that reads from an Excel file, it will not work with 64-bit Office installed."

Comment: Side note: if you ever want to build an SSIS package that reads from an Excel file, it will not work with 64-bit Office installed. Also, you're correct about the Access Engine.

Comment: @ederollora  thanks for your advice.  I'll try reinstall the office and check

Comment: In my case I had the 64-bit version of Office installed but I was using the 32-bit JDK. So installing the 64-bit JDK worked in my case. If I were you I would try first to download the 32-bit version of your JDK, and try with that)

Comment: Look for the 32 bit version you need here (first you need to know which JDK you are using): http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/archive-139210.html